# Admin logo magento-icon.svg missing after first install

Tags: adminhtml

Just installed `Magento-CE-2.0.4-2016-03-31-10-50-04` and install went fine, but the following file is missing:

`www.example.com/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/images/magento-icon.svg`

In fact, the directory

`www.example.com/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/images/` is missing (no images directory in `en_US`).

I selected English (Australian) as my default language at setup, but there is no 
`www.example.com/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_AU` folder.

I guess this issue may be presented to other Magento CE users who select `English (Australian)` as their default language at setup too.

For a short term fix, I'd like to find an official copy of `magento-icon.svg`.

Help appreciated.